# Create an image with 5 bits for each pixel

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I have an image with which consists of 8 bits for each pixel, how I can create new picture that consists of 5 bits for each pixel using python and OpenCV?

I know that in an RGB image, each pixel is represented by three 8 bit numbers associated to the values for Red, Green, Blue respectively, but I can't figure it out how I can create an image from 8 bits for each pixel to a new image with 5 bits of each pixel.

Comment: You would use any graphics library that supports both formats.

Comment: @stark what do you mean with ```both formats``` ?

Comment: why do you want an image with 5 bits per each pixel? are you sure you don't want something like rgb565 maybe?

Comment: @Miki my customer wants it, I really don't know how to do it even with lot of google searching

Comment: not sure how do do it in python, but in other languages you typically use bit-shifts to separate some bit-fields out of a number that is represented in higher bits. In the same way you can place n bits inside any region of a bigger memory region. Often bitwise AND and bitwise OR operators are used as well.

Comment: I wonder if you’re speaking of color palettes instead such as presented here: https://cscie12.dce.harvard.edu/lecture_notes/2007-08/20080312/slide18.html However, using the gif approach also requires scene-specific palettes, which means there isn’t one general solution.

Comment: crosspost: https://forum.opencv.org/t/how-to-create-an-image-with-5-or-4-bits-for-each-pixel/8192

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can rescale the value of the pixels i.e. multiply every pixel value with 32/256 (or just divide by 8) if you want to generate a mapping value on 5 bit scale for your image.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Quite wrong.  3 5-bit pixels packed in a 16-bit word is a common format. (or 565)

Comment: Thanks for advocating `32/256`. Many people would say `31/255` which is just wrong.

Comment: depends on the definition of the color space, and whether you want the maximum value to represent 100% or not, @MarkRansom

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz if you use `31/255` then only one single input of 255 will deliver 31.  All the other output values can be generated by many inputs, so 31 will be massively underrepresented in the conversion.  I don't see how the color space definition would enter into it.